# mejorar el rendimiento trabajando con array

Tags: python, array, numpy, rendimiento

El siguiente código aplica el algoritmo de Kmeans para la resolucion de agrupamientos.

Esta formado por un conjunto de metodos intermedios para ir desarrolando el algoritmo.

El problema que observo es que por trabajar con listas, el mismo no tiene buen rendimiento. Es lento cuando se ejecuta el metodo show()

Hasta el metodo P() va bien, luego al pasar al metodo K(). Todo es mas lento.

Segun comprendo todo deberia mejorar si utilizo array en ves de listas

En el codigo hay algunos comentarios para comprender un poco lo que hace cada método.

Tambien comprendo que el metodo CA() se podria mejorar

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import operator

class KM:
    def __init__(self,puntos= [],centroides= []):
        self.puntos= puntos
        self.centroides= centroides
        #self.color = None

        colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(self.centroides)))

    def DI(self):
        """
        genera matriz de distancia de los centroides a todos los puntos
        """
        D= []   
        MD= []
        #P = np.zeros((len(self.centroides),len(self.puntos)))

        for i in range(len(self.centroides)):
            for j in range(len(self.puntos)):
                D.append(np.sqrt((self.centroides[i][0]-self.puntos[j][0]) **2 + (self.centroides[i][1]-self.puntos[j][1]) **2))
        MD = np.array(D).reshape(len(self.centroides),len(self.puntos)) # recorta el vector dintancias "D" y forma la matriz "MD"

        return MD


    def P(self): #P(self,X) ------- matriz de pertenencia . correponde "uno" cuando pertece y "cero" cuando no

        P = np.zeros((len(self.centroides),len(self.puntos)))
        for i in range(len(self.puntos)):
            P[self.DI()[:,i].tolist().index(np.min(self.DI()[:,i]))][i]=1   
        return P  


    def K(self): # metodo para formar lista de clusters
        d = []
        s = []
        KC = []

        for i in range(len(c)):
            for j in range(len(self.puntos)):
                if self.P()[i,:][j]==1:
                    #np.append(d,self.puntos[j],axis=None)
                    d.append(self.puntos[j]) # reordena la lista
            s.append(sum(self.P()[i,:])) #optiene la cantida de elemento de cada cluster
        i=0
        for k in range(len(s)):
            i=i+int(s[k])
            KC.append(d[i-int(s[k]):i]) #separa a la lista "d" en sub listas formando los clusters
            KA=np.array(KC)
        return KC


    def CA(self): #actualiza los centroides
        Xc=[]
        Xs=0
        X=[]

        Yc=[]
        Ys=0
        Y=[]

        centroidesA=[]

        for i in range(len(c)):
            for j in range(len(self.K()[i])):
                Xs=Xs+(self.K()[i][j][0])
                Ys=Ys+(self.K()[i][j][1])
            Xc.append(Xs/len(self.K()[i]))        
            Yc.append(Ys/len(self.K()[i]))
            Xs=0
            Ys=0 
        for i in range(len(c)):
            centroidesA.append([Xc[i],Yc[i]])
        return centroidesA      


    def show(self): # metodo de visualizacion

        fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()           
        """
        grafica puntos
        """
        colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(self.centroides)))
        for i in range(len(self.centroides)):
            ax1.scatter(self.centroides[i][0], self.centroides[i][1], marker='o', color=colors[i], s=80)
            for j in range(len(self.K()[i])):    
                ax1.scatter(self.K()[i][j][0], self.K()[i][j][1], marker='o', color=colors[i], s=20) 

        title = 'puntos'
        #plt.xlabel('X')
        #plt.ylabel('Y')
        plt.title(title)
        # plt.savefig('{}.png'.format(title))
        fig.show()
```

Comment: Supongo que también será algo lento DI()... Tienes bucles dentro de bucles en todos esos métodos que mencionas (lógicamente trabajando con matrices es lo que toca). Si trabajas con muchos datos como intuyo que harás, es normal que en esos métodos lo notes. Una solución interesante puede ser la de paralelizar esos métodos. Tienes la librería multiprocessing en Python que te permite esto, y harás que tu código corra bastante más rápido. Te dejo aquí una guía bastante interesante.  https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/

Comment: Hola Adrian. Leere el articulo que mencionas. Me han realizado un aporte al metodo K() donde elimino dos bucle y en su reemplazo uso: d = np.vstack([p[filtro == 1.] for filtro in self.P()]). La mejora es considerable! Vere de ir reemplazando los bucles por funciones de NumPy

Comment: Se que se sale del problema que planteas, pero ¿te has planteado (o puedes) usar alguna biblioteca existente como [sklearn.cluster.KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)?

Comment: FJSevilla. Lo cierto es que soy un aprendiz de python. Tome este problema como un comienzo para mejorar mis conocimientos. Tengo que mejorar los bucles. Luego de tu ayuda creo que el metodo que genera menor rendimiento es el "CA()" que opinas?